# (PYTHON) Update a variable in a list with a dictionnary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I must say I'm rather new to Python and I can't figure how to solve my problem.

I have a list which looks like this

```
ligne = ['DR', '0.8282312925170068']
```

and I want it to have one extra element:

```
ligne = ['DETECTION RATE', 'DR', '0.8282312925170068'].
```

The problem is I need to put the right attribute for each list.
What I did was

```
    for line in f.readlines():
        ligne = line.split()
        for step in {
            "DR" : (ligne = ["Detection Rate"] + ligne),
            "FAR" :(ligne = ["False Alarm Rate"] +ligne),
            "FNR" :(ligne = ["False N Rate"] + ligne),
            "MOTA":(ligne = ["MOTA"] + ligne),
            "MOTP":(ligne = ["MOTP"] + ligne),
            "PFR":(ligne = ["PFR"] + ligne),
            "Precision":(ligne = ["Precision"] + ligne),
        }.get(ligne[0]):step()
```

but this is not working since (ligne = ["Detection Rate"] + ligne) is not a function.

How cani do this?

Comment: `ligne = ["Detection Rate"] + ligne` you cannot put that as a dictionary value.

Comment: Seems like [py-motmetrics](https://github.com/cheind/py-motmetrics) could also be useful to you (disclaimer - I'm the author of that library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is overcomplex and syntaxically incorrect. Since you just need to prefix, just create a dictionary keyword => prefix:

```
d = {"DR":"Detection Rate","FAR":"False Alarm Rate","FNR":"False N Rate"}
```

then prepend the value (and if the token isn't in the dictionary, repeat the key, it covers half of your values apparently):

```
for line in f:
    ligne = line.split()
    key = ligne[0]
    ligne.insert(0,d.get(key,key))
```

EDIT: comments hint at a trailing colon after the first word. Just change to:

```
key = ligne[0].rstrip(":")
ligne.insert(0,d.get(key,key)+":")
```

Notes:

- `insert` works in place: saves some temp list creation (doesn't save element shifting, though)
- `for line in f` avoids reading the file at once. It just reads line by line.

Comment: this is the output:

Comment: ['DR:', 'DR:', '0.8282312925170068']
['FAR:', 'FAR:', '0.6227730441518203']
['FNR:', 'FNR:', '0.1717687074829932']
['MOTA:', 'MOTA:', '-0.554421768707483']
['MOTP:', 'MOTP:', '0.5425643298357187']
['PFR:', 'PFR:', '0.03571428571428571']
['Precision:', 'Precision:', '0.3772269558481797']
['Recall:', 'Recall:', '0.8282312925170068']

as you can see it does not take the correct attribute from the dictionary

Comment: of course: your keys have a trailing colon, see my edit (that wasn't in your question)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't working because `{ }` is a dictionary (a data structure) and your code is trying to use it like a `switch` statement.

Set up your equivalences first:

```
translation = {
        "DR"  :"Detection Rate",
        "FAR" :"False Alarm Rate",
        "FNR" :"False N Rate"}
```

There is no need to translate literals that translate to themselves.

```
for line in f.readlines():
    ligne = line.split()
    ligne = [translation.get(ligne[0],ligne[0])] + ligne
```

Comment: yes,I was trying to simulate a switch.
My code takes one list, adds a prefix to it, and then appends it into another list to create a list of lists

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement. The tutorial says use `if...elif...else`. But in this case all you have to do is tease the data and the code apart, and you end up with a much simpler solution. Which is why you got two almost identical answers.

Answer (score 1):

make a list of new variable:

```
Vlist=['Detection Rate','False', 'Alarm Rate','False N 
    Rate','MOTA','MOTP','PFR','Precision']
```

make a empty for new lines(added with new variable) in txt

```
newline=[]
```

loop from first newV and newline in file and concatenate together

```
for line,newV in zip(f.readlines(),Vlist):
    ligne=line.split()
    newV+=ligne
    newline+=' '.join(newV)
```

rewrite the newlines to the file

```
for i in newline:
    f.write(i)
```